# How to get key/value pair from NSDictionary?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, json, nsdictionary

I need little help with NSDictionary. How can I get 1 pair, lets say a value for "id" if I have dictionary

```
NSDictionary *allCourses = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:allCoursesData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
```

and it looks like this:

[image: NSDictionary allCourses]

Thanks for Your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The shortest way:

```
NSNumber *number = allCourses[@"semacko"][@"id"];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
NSDictionary *allCourses = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:allCoursesData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
        [allCourses enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock: ^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
    // do something with key and obj
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDictionary *semacko = [allCourses objectForKey:@"semacko"];
NSNumber *number = [semacko objectForKey:@"id"];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSNumber *number = allCourses[@"semacko"][@"id"];
```

or if you want to iterate all objects:

```
for(NSDictionary* course in allCourses) {
    NSNumber *number = course[@"id"];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *name =[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",[Dictionaryname objectForKey:@"key"]];
```

by this code you can access the value that corresponds to the key that specified in the objectforkey keyword

Comment: Could you add some detail to make this answer more digestible for the entire community?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
NSNumber *courseID = [allCourses valueForKeyPath:@"semacko.id"];
```

For setting value:

```
- setValue:forKeyPath:
```