# Get Property within an Object within a Dictionary - Objective C

Tags: objective-c, object, dictionary, properties

I need to access a property within a dictionary and I am having a difficult time doing so.

Dictionary:

```
{
  Id = "123";
  Animal = {
     Id = "456";
     Type = "Dog";
     Sound = "Bark";
  }
}
```

Code:

```
NSString *animalType = dictionary[@"Animal.Type"];
```

All I get back is (null). What would be the proper way to call this in order to get "Dog"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get key/value pair from NSDictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21824528/how-to-get-key-value-pair-from-nsdictionary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
NSString *animalType = dictionary[@"Animal"][@"Type"];
```

Or

```
NSString *animalType = [[dictionary objectForKey:@"Animal"] objectForKey:@"Type"];
```