# Reach Child Key Without Knowing Parent's Key Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, json, firebase

I have this data returned from Firebase. In my app, I have a search part in which users can search other users by their nicknames. But I'm retrieving all users and I needed to pass all users to find a wanted nickname. As you can see I'm saving users with their uids which I don't store.
So I need to reach the nickname key without knowing the parent key.

```
7zsRWD4QraQVJiONdqKLhsn5xI73 =     {
        followed =         (
            7zsRWD4QraQVJiONdqKLhsn5xI73,
            7zsRWD4QraQVJiONdqKLhsn5xI73,
            7zsRWD4QraQVJiONdqKLhsn5xI73,
            vexD00nIPsb6MHfuw2w8Wod9fNF3
        );
        icon = "man.png";
        itiraf =         (
                        {
                description = Kgkgkkgk;
                itirafId = 20191121144558916686058;
                title = Mcnckckg;
            },

        );
        nickName = Oykuycj;
    };
    oLajRgtaRIZktecSXzo4HcZlU252 =     {
        followed =         (
            oLajRgtaRIZktecSXzo4HcZlU252,
            oLajRgtaRIZktecSXzo4HcZlU252,
            oLajRgtaRIZktecSXzo4HcZlU252,
            oLajRgtaRIZktecSXzo4HcZlU252
        );
        icon = "man-4.png";
        in = 1;
        itiraf =         (
                        {
                description = "M\U0131mu";
                itirafId = 2019112813101124788975;
                title = Kmkm;
            }
        );
        nickName = 5678999;
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by using a for-each loop. I'm saving my data to userDic which is a NSDictionary. Here's my code search key is the wanted nickname and key taking all user ids one by one. So I can reach nicknames without knowing uids.

```
    for (NSString* key in userDic) {
        NSString *nick = [userDic[key] objectForKey:@"nickName"];
        if([nick isEqualToString:searchKey]){
            NSLog(@"user found");
            break;
        }

    }
```

Comment: `[userDic enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock ...]` would be way more efficient. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/21824670/5329717